# Как с помощью регулярных выражений убрать лишние запятые?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка такого вида:
`Олег, Витя,,,Петя, Эдик,, Валера`
Есть ли возможность при помощи регулярного выражения убрать лишние запятые и привести строку к виду:
`Олег,Витя,Петя,Эдик,Валера`

Comment: Да, такая возможность есть. https://regex101.com/r/GJ55oa/1

Answer (score -1):

вот рабочий вариант
`$string = preg_replace("/,+/", ",", $string);`